# Suggestions for data extraction Data in fortran

Tags: algorithm, loops, fortran

I use F95/90 and IBM compiler. I am trying to extract the numerical values from block and write in a file. I am facing a strange error in the output which I cannot understand. Every time I execute the program it skips the loop between 'Beta' and 'END'. I am trying to read and store the values. 
The number of lines inside the Alpha- and Beta loops are not fixed. So a simple 'do loop' is of no use to me. I tried the 'do while' loop and also 'if-else' but it still skips the 'Beta' part.

```
Alpha Singles Amplitudes
15      3    23      4   -0.186952
15      3    26      4    0.599918
15      3    31      4    0.105048
15      3    23      4    0.186952
Beta  Singles Amplitudes
15      3    23      4    0.186952
15      3    26      4   -0.599918
15      3    31      4   -0.105048
15      3    23      4   -0.186952
END `
```

The simple short code is :

```
program test_read

   implicit none

      integer::nop,a,b,c,d,e,i,j,k,l,m,ios
      double precision::r,t,rr
      character::dummy*300
      character*15::du1,du2,du3
      open (unit=10, file="1.txt", status='old',form='formatted')

  100   read(10,'(a100)')dummy

        if (dummy(1:3)=='END') goto 200

        if(dummy(2:14)=='Alpha Singles') then
             i=0
  160       read(10,'(a4,i2,a6,i1,a4,i2,a6,i1,f12.6)')du1,b,du2,c,du3,d,du4,e,r              
            do while(du1.ne.' Bet') 
    write(*,'(a2,a4,i2,a6,i1,a4,i2,a6,i1,f12.6)')'AS',du1,b,du2,c,du3,d,du4,e,r
    goto 160
    end do                     

        elseif (dummy(2:14)=='Beta  Singles') then
  170       read(10,'(a4,i2,a6,i1,a4,i2,a6,i1,f12.6)')du1,b,du2,c,du3,d,du4,e,r
            if((du1=='END'))then
              stop
        else      

     write(*,'(a2,a4,i2,a6,i1,a4,i2,a6,i1,f12.6)')'BS',du1,b,du2,c,du3,d,du4,e,r             
            goto 170      
    end if
    end if
        goto 100      

   200    print*,'This is the end' 

  end program test_read
```

Comment: jumping around with gotos like that is very very bad practice.  There is no reason ever to use  goto in fortran - as you see it makes debugging really painful.

Answer (score 1):

Your program never gets out of the loop which checks for Beta because when your while loop exits, it has already read the line with Beta.  It then goes to 100 which reads the next line after Beta, so you never actually see Beta  Singles.  Try the following

```
character(len=2):: tag
read(10,'(a100)')dummy

do while (dummy(1:3).ne.'END')
    if (dummy(2:14)=='Alpha Singles') then
       tag = 'AS'
    else if (dummy(2:14)=='Beta  Singles') then
       tag = 'BS'
    else
       read(dummy,'(a4,i2,a6,i1,a4,i2,a6,i1,f12.6)')du1,b,du2,c,du3,d,du4,e,r              
       write(*,'(a2,a4,i2,a6,i1,a4,i2,a6,i1,f12.6)')tag,du1,b,du2,c,du3,d,du4,e,r
    end if
    read(10, '(a100)') dummy
 end do

 print*,'This is the end'
```